# WPF/C#: Merge 4 Images into 1 Image (Tile effect)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, merge

I was able to get and retrieve 4 images coming from my local folder and place them on `Image1`, `Image2`, `Image3`, and `Image4` (`Image` controls)

Is it possible to merge these 4 images into 1 image file, creating a 2 x 2 tile effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a WriteableBitmap. If the 4 images are the same size then create the WriteableBitmap twice as wide and twice as high as one of the images and then copy the image data from each image into the WriteableBitmap.